# How to give a variable path for GetFolder in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

This script basically goes to a folder and list all the files in that folder and output it in a txt file. Now instead of defining the folder path I want it to use the txt file that contains a bunch of folder paths in it and I want to loop that txt file. How can I do this?

```
Dim fso
Dim ObjFolder
Dim ObjOutFile
Dim ObjFiles
Dim ObjFile

'Creating File System Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Getting the Folder Object
Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Susan\Desktop\Anime\ova")

'Creating an Output File to write the File Names
Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Susan\Documents\iMacros\Macros\WindowsFiles.txt")

'Getting the list of Files
Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

'Writing Name and Path of each File to Output File
For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Path)
Next

ObjOutFile.Close
```

Comment: Is the text file containing the folder paths the same text file containing the files in the folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruriko, this should be a working version, i would add a check to see if the inputfile exist, i'm sure you can do that yourself.

```
Dim fso, ObjFolder, ObjOutFile, ObjFiles, ObjFile, outputFile, inputFileList
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8, CreateIfNeeded = true

inputFileList = "list.txt"
outputFile = "C:\Users\Susan\Documents\iMacros\Macros\WindowsFiles.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = fso.OpenTextFile(inputFileList, ForReading)

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
 sFolderName = objTextFile.Readline
 wscript.Echo "writing contents of " & sFolderName
 writefilenames(sFolderName)
Loop

function writefilenames(sFolderName)
  Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder(sFolderName)

  If fso.FileExists(outputFile) Then
    Set ObjOutFile = fso.OpenTextFile(outputFile, ForAppending)
  Else
    Set ObjOutFile = fso.OpenTextFile(outputFile, ForWriting, CreateIfNeeded)
  End If

  Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

  For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Path)
  Next

  ObjOutFile.Close
end function
```